# Is it feasible to train an RNN model on sequential data within a small time range?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to predict the value of the next time step based on previous ones using RNN models. I have read some useful blogs and official examples, in which they usually have a long sequential data of the same object and generate training and testing data with some sliding window approaches (e.g. **daily** weather records for the last 10 years of a city, so there're 3650 time steps and N concessive time steps consist of a sample).

My problem is a bit different. I don't have many time steps (just about 20) of the same object, but I have time-series data of many similar objects within the same time range. (e.g. I have the **annual** weather records for the last 10 years of all Asian cities, so there're only 10 time steps for each city, and I treated all data of a single city as a sample)

So my question is:

1. Is it feasible to train an RNN model on my data? (I tried, and the training loss decreased while the validation loss had little change)
2. How should I normalize my input? (I am confusing if I could concatenate them all as a single long time series and normalize them. Or just normalize the features by the same object one by one)

My code:

```
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(14,11), return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

    history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_test_scaled, y_test))
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you only have a single window and want the RNN to predict merely based on that window and there's no a rolling window over a long time series. Am I right?

Comment: @frogatto Yes, you're right. I have single-window data for each object.

Comment: So, a Keras stateless RNN sounds to be a good option. What have you already tried?

Comment: @frogatto If the default settings of a Keras RNN is stateless, then I have tried it. But my validation loss doesn't decrease much as the training loss does. So I am wondering if I do it in an appropriate way, since different objects have common and also distinct patterns in the same window.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @frogatto Thanks for your help, I have posted my code